# Defaulting to a drawn image when the image is not present WPF / C# / MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, viewbox

I am displaying images inside a listbox template with MVVM (Caliburn Micro) connected to a List of my custom object. The ImagePath is connected to the string ImageFilePath property of the custom object

`<Image x:Name="SelectedQuestion_ImageFilePath"/>`

This all works fine if the image is present it gets displayed as it should but if there is no image present (which is sometimes intended) of course nothing is displayed.

Now i would like to draw a default image in runtime instead of loading an default image in order to save ressources.

I have a viewbox that contains a canvas in a ressource dictionary (exported vector image from adobe illustrator)

```
<Viewbox x:Key="NoImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas Width="725.000" Height="725.000">
        <Path Fill="{StaticResource ImageDark}" Data="F1 M 361.940,251.875 C 325.880,252.469 298.132,221.631 298.142,187.365 C 298.152,152.274 327.169,123.108 361.941,123.125 C 398.106,123.143 426.859,151.639 426.872,187.476 C 426.885,223.276 398.049,251.874 361.940,251.875 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="{StaticResource ImageDark}" Data="F1 M 185.015,300.273 C 273.070,406.383 360.574,511.829 448.560,617.856 C 460.198,605.273 471.239,593.364 482.247,581.425 C 493.686,569.019 505.078,556.570 516.518,544.164 C 528.748,530.902 540.973,517.636 553.267,504.433 C 563.657,493.275 574.190,482.250 584.564,471.077 C 589.274,466.004 593.657,460.627 598.360,455.547 C 605.755,447.559 613.295,439.705 621.100,431.449 C 640.417,451.640 659.258,471.333 678.790,491.749 C 678.790,342.665 678.790,194.962 678.790,47.180 C 468.076,47.180 257.696,47.180 47.202,47.180 C 47.202,186.157 47.202,324.828 47.202,464.975 C 93.504,409.639 138.946,355.330 185.015,300.273 Z M 17.523,17.322 C 248.061,17.322 478.159,17.322 708.566,17.322 C 708.566,247.735 708.566,477.952 708.566,708.521 C 478.353,708.521 248.137,708.521 17.523,708.521 C 17.523,478.323 17.523,247.990 17.523,17.322 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="{StaticResource ImageLight}" Data="F1 M 17.523,17.322 C 17.523,247.990 17.523,478.323 17.523,708.521 C 248.137,708.521 478.353,708.521 708.566,708.521 C 708.566,477.952 708.566,247.735 708.566,17.322 C 478.159,17.322 248.061,17.322 17.523,17.322 Z M 725.000,725.000 C 483.333,725.000 241.667,725.000 0.000,725.000 C 0.000,483.333 0.000,241.667 0.000,0.000 C 241.667,0.000 483.333,0.000 725.000,0.000 C 725.000,241.667 725.000,483.333 725.000,725.000 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="{StaticResource ImageLight}" Data="F1 M 361.940,251.875 C 398.049,251.874 426.885,223.276 426.872,187.476 C 426.859,151.639 398.106,123.143 361.941,123.125 C 327.169,123.108 298.152,152.274 298.142,187.365 C 298.132,221.631 325.880,252.469 361.940,251.875 Z M 185.015,300.273 C 138.946,355.330 93.504,409.639 47.202,464.975 C 47.202,324.828 47.202,186.157 47.202,47.180 C 257.696,47.180 468.076,47.180 678.790,47.180 C 678.790,194.962 678.790,342.665 678.790,491.749 C 659.258,471.333 640.417,451.640 621.100,431.449 C 613.295,439.705 605.755,447.559 598.360,455.547 C 593.657,460.627 589.274,466.004 584.564,471.077 C 574.190,482.250 563.657,493.275 553.267,504.433 C 540.973,517.636 528.748,530.902 516.518,544.164 C 505.078,556.570 493.686,569.019 482.247,581.425 C 471.239,593.364 460.198,605.273 448.560,617.856 C 360.574,511.829 273.070,406.383 185.015,300.273 Z"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

If I add it manually as static ressource of a contentControl it also works fine.

Now i would like to display this viewbox every time there is no image present in the property of the custom object but I obviously cannot replace the image with a viewbox directly.
[Example how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLql8.png)

Anybody got a proper way to approach this?

Comment: "*I obviously cannot replace the image with a viewbox directly*" - why not? You could use a DataTemplateSelector to select from two different DataTemplates, one with an Image, one with the ViewBox. Set the ListBox's ItemTemplateSelector.

Comment: @Clemens
i will try that thanks. That DataTemplateSelector is probably what I was after, I had not heard about it jet. Thanks already!